# Blender: stream blender OpenGL context to another OpenGL window

Tags: python, opengl, blender

Is it possible to stream a blender scene to another OpenGL window, via some kind of a server for remote rendering?  I saw that `bpy` can inspect the scene graph and has access to OpenGL but I couldn't find any resources.

Comment: If you want to transmit just the window pixels, then Blender has a HTTP based frame server built-in for just that.

Comment: Thank you, a more detailed example, or a link? But yes, sounds like, this will be able to stream a blender scene to another independant opengl window.